# udp server bind multiple interfaces,recv succeed,but send back failed

Tags: sockets, networking, interface, udp

My server (ubuntu) has three network cards, each card corresponds to an independent ip.
I use udp bind port 1234 INADDR_ANY,
I execute the command lsof -i: 1234 display
udp *: 1234
I use the udp client to send messages to the server with three ip, the server shows that the message has been received
But the server sends a response message to the client only the first ip of the network card to respond successfully, I use tcpdump found that the server no matter from which ip received the message, the response message is the first ip card used. so through the other two NIC's ip connection to the client is not receiving the server's message back
I tried tcp is not the problem, how to solve this situation

Comment: "_My server (ubuntu) has three network cards, each card corresponds to an independent ip._" There are only two IPs: IPv4 and IPv6. What other IP do you think you have?

Comment: my question base on IPV4

Comment: You said you have three independent IPs. There are only two.